# error: incompatible types in assignment

Tags: c

My C code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "help.h"

int test(int x, P *ut) {
    int point = 10;

    ut->dt[10].max_x = NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

my help.h file code

```
typedef struct{
    double max_x;
    double max_y;
}X;

typedef struct{
    X dt[10];
}P;
```

I got an error i.e

```
error: incompatible types in assignment
```

error comes in here

```
ut->dt[10].max_x = NULL;
```

can anybody help me.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to set a double value to `NULL`, which even if compiles, is mixing two incompatible terms. (In some versions of the C class library `NULL` is defined simply as `0`, in others as `(void*)0` - in latter case you get an error for such code.)

Moreover, you try to access index 10 of an array of size 10, which is out of bounds - the elements are indexed from 0 to 9. So try this:

```
ut->dt[9].max_x = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see two problems in

```
ut->dt[10].max_x = NULL;
```

- The index `10` is not valid, it
  should be 0-9
- You are assigning a `NULL` value to a
  double. I guess you meant `0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

1. max_x is of type double, NULL is of type (void *). What makes you think they are compatible?

   Try `ut->dt[10].max_x = 0.0;`
2. Accessing dt[10] is out of bounds, array indexing starts at 0!